How to display author's name and translator's name?
How to display the name of an author and the name of a translator into a book reference? This is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{Bion1983,
author = {Bion, Wilfred R.}, 
title = {Réflexion faite}, 
 year = {2005}, 
 origdate={1967},
translator={Robert, François},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Bion1983}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


What do you mean by «to display the name of an author and the name of a translator into a book reference»?
If you mean citing them within the text, you can use the \citeauthor command for the author and then you can create a \citetranslator command in a similar way for the translator.
Otherwise, I don't understand the problem. The author's name appears both in the citation and in the reference list. With the ext-verbose style, it always appears in citations. The translator's name too appears by default in the reference list and at the first citation in the text which is in full form.

If you are looking for the \citetranslator command, try the next one.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetranslator}{\boolfalse{citetracker}\boolfalse{pagetracker}\usebibmacro{prenote}}{\printnames[default]{translator}}{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

OK. I had a problem with my references manager. It works fine with ext-verbose.
